# GCD deadlock on OS X but not on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have this code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    NSLog(@"First");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Third");
        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
            NSLog(@"Fourth");
        });
        NSLog(@"Last");
    });
    NSLog(@"Second");
}
```

which prints out:

```
2015-07-20 19:12:54.325 Test[7574:431705] First
2015-07-20 19:12:54.326 Test[7574:431736] Third
2015-07-20 19:12:54.326 Test[7574:431736] Fourth
2015-07-20 19:12:54.326 Test[7574:431705] Second
2015-07-20 19:12:54.326 Test[7574:431736] Last
```

This also differs on some executions. Sometimes it prints "First, Second, Third, Fourth, Last" and other times it produces the the output above.

Also, I have a `test.m` file with the following:
    #include

```
int main() {
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
  NSLog(@"First");
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      NSLog(@"Third");
      dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
          NSLog(@"Fourth");
        });
      NSLog(@"Last");
    });
  NSLog(@"Second");
  return 0;
}
```

And this produces:

```
2015-07-20 19:12:36.067 tester[7568:431388] First
2015-07-20 19:12:36.068 tester[7568:431388] Second
```

I don't understand why on the iOS Simulator it prints out all of the logs while on Mac it prints "First" and "Second" then deadlocks. I expected the iOS code to deadlock also but instead it prints out the "Third" and "Fourth". There isn't any other that deals with threading in the iOS code. Also when `NSLog(@"First")` is commented out, on some executions of `test.m` it produces something different as shown below:

```
$: ./tester
2015-07-20 19:19:31.030 tester[7608:433729] Second
$: ./tester
2015-07-20 19:19:32.268 tester[7609:433738] Third
2015-07-20 19:19:32.268 tester[7609:433737] Second
$ ./tester
2015-07-20 19:19:32.620 tester[7610:433740] Second
$: ./tester
2015-07-20 19:19:33.812 tester[7611:433744] Third
2015-07-20 19:19:33.812 tester[7611:433743] Second
```

I have no idea what is causing the difference in output. Is it the way iOS handles threading that differs from OS X? I would appreciate if anyone could explain what is going on

Comment: It doesn't appear to deadlock. It seems that `main` simply returns (and the app terminates) before the background thread has a chance to run or complete.

Comment: I second @rmaddy's suggestion. Can you either use a `dispatch_group` to ensure you're waiting for the background task to finish, or as a simpler test, just sleep the main thread?

Comment: Ah didn't think of that but after sleeping the main thread at the end it seems to go through all of it. Also after sleeping the main thread the inconsistency in logs seems to disappear also. I thought the `dispatch_async` returns immediately so `Second` would print always no matter what

Comment: `Second` will always print, no matter what. But it won't _necessarily_ print immediately after `First`. There's a chance that the background thread will begin executing earlier.

Comment: I meant "Second" would always print second but as the answer says there's another concurrent thread. I thought `dispatch_async` returned then created the thread but guess not. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac you do not have a deadlock. It is a simple case of `main` completing and the app terminating before the background thread has a chance to start or complete.

Keep in mind also that the order of seeing "Second" and "Third" in the log is undefined. By the time `dispatch_async` returns, you now have two concurrent threads so the `NSLog` on the main queue and the background queue could get output in either order.

If you block the main thread (such as using `sleep`) just before the `return` statement, you should see all logs from both threads.